# WPF Custom ProgressBar in a User Control Library doesn't update itself but everytyhing else works fine

Tags: wpf, vb.net

i've made a user control library to make a custom progress bar that changes color upon reaching a certain value and showing in a label it's value, everything works fine except the progress bar doesn't update it's gui here's the code.

User Control Library XAML

```
<UserControl
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:sfjahgiga" x:Class="UserControl1" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="540" Height="103">
<UserControl.Resources>

</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>

    <local:CustomControl1 x:Name="ProgressBar1" Margin="10,10,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=mCurrentValue,UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"/>

    <Label x:Name="Label1" Content="{Binding Value, ElementName=ProgressBar1, Mode=TwoWay}" ContentStringFormat=" {0} %" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" Margin="212,34,204,41" BorderBrush="Transparent"/>

</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

User Control Library Code-Behind

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Public Class UserControl1


Private mMaxValue As New Integer


Public Shared ValueProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("mCurrentValue", GetType(Double), GetType(UserControl1), New PropertyMetadata(AddressOf OnStatusChanged))

Private Shared Sub OnStatusChanged(sender As DependencyObject, e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    CType(sender, UserControl1).ProgressBar1.Value = e.NewValue
End Sub

Public Property mCurrentValue As Double
    Get
        Return CDbl(GetValue(ValueProperty))
    End Get
    Set(value As Double)
        SetValue(ValueProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property


Public Sub New()

    InitializeComponent()



    With ProgressBar1
        Dim Brush1 As New SolidColorBrush
        Brush1.Color = ConvertToRbg("#FF0000")
        .Resources.Add("BrushRed", Brush1)

        Dim Brush2 As New SolidColorBrush
        Brush2.Color = ConvertToRbg("#FFFF00")
        .Resources.Add("BrushYellow", Brush2)

        Dim Brush3 As New SolidColorBrush
        Brush3.Color = ConvertToRbg("#FF2EFF00")
        .Resources.Add("BrushGreen", Brush3)
    End With

End Sub



#Region "Functions"

Public Property GetColor1() As String

    Get
        With ProgressBar1
            Return .Resources("BrushRed").Color.ToString
        End With
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        With ProgressBar1
            Dim Brush As New SolidColorBrush
            Brush.Color = ConvertToRbg(value)
            .Resources("BrushRed") = Brush
        End With
    End Set

End Property

Public Property GetColor2() As String
    Get
        With ProgressBar1
            Return .Resources("BrushYellow").Color.ToString
        End With
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        With ProgressBar1
            Dim Brush As New SolidColorBrush
            Brush.Color = ConvertToRbg(value)
            .Resources("BrushYellow") = Brush
        End With
    End Set
End Property

Public Property GetColor3() As String
    Get
        With ProgressBar1
            Return .Resources("BrushGreen").Color.ToString
        End With
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        With ProgressBar1
            Dim Brush As New SolidColorBrush
            Brush.Color = ConvertToRbg(value)
            .Resources("BrushGreen") = Brush
        End With
    End Set
End Property

Public Property GetMaxValue() As Integer
    Get
        Return mMaxValue
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        mMaxValue = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Function GetCurrentColor()
    Return ProgressBar1.Foreground.ToString
End Function

Public Function GetCurrentProgress()
    Return ProgressBar1.Value.ToString
End Function

Public Function GetLabelContent()
    Return Label1.Content.ToString
End Function

Private Function ConvertToRbg(ByVal HexColor As String) As Color
    Dim Red As String
    Dim Green As String
    Dim Blue As String
    HexColor = Replace(HexColor, "#", "")
    Red = Val("&H" & Mid(HexColor, 1, 2))
    Green = Val("&H" & Mid(HexColor, 3, 2))
    Blue = Val("&H" & Mid(HexColor, 5, 2))
    Return Color.FromRgb(Red, Green, Blue)
End Function

#End Region

Public Sub ChangeColor()
    With ProgressBar1
        Dim prgrss As Double = .Value / 100

        Dim redbrsh As SolidColorBrush = .Resources("BrushRed")
        Dim grnbrsh As SolidColorBrush = .Resources("BrushGreen")
        Dim ylwbrsh As SolidColorBrush = .Resources("BrushYellow")


        If prgrss = 1D Then

            .Foreground = grnbrsh

        ElseIf prgrss >= 0.95D And prgrss < 1D Then

            .Foreground = ylwbrsh
        Else
            .Foreground = redbrsh
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub ChangeValue(ByVal value As Double)
    mCurrentValue = value
    Dim be As BindingExpression = ProgressBar1.GetBindingExpression(ProgressBar.ValueProperty)
    be.UpdateSource()
End Sub

Private Sub ProgressBar1_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs(Of Double)) Handles ProgressBar1.ValueChanged
    ChangeColor()
End Sub

End Class
```

WPF Application XAML

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
xmlns:sfjahgiga="clr-namespace:sfjahgiga;assembly=sfjahgiga" x:Class="MainWindow"
Title="MainWindow" Height="461" Width="525" Opacity="2" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Grid Margin="0,0,0,-20">
    <ProgressBar x:Name="PrgBar" Margin="10,317,10,83"
        Value="{Binding Value, ElementName=ProgressSlider}" IsIndeterminate="False" Background="#d3d3d3" Foreground="{DynamicResource BrushYellow}">
        <ProgressBar.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BrushRed" Color="#FFFF0000"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BrushGreen" Color="#FF2EFF00"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BrushYellow" Color="#FFFF00"/>
        </ProgressBar.Resources>
    </ProgressBar>
    <Label x:Name="LblProgress" Margin="204,317,196,96" Content="0%" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" Height=" 38" />
    <Slider x:Name="ProgressSlider" Margin="10,10,10,276" Minimum="0" Maximum="100"/>
    <Label x:Name="LblProva" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,44,0,0" Width="162" Height="132"/>
    <sfjahgiga:UserControl1 x:Name="ProgressBarSF" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="106" Width="497" Margin="10,181,0,0"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

WPF Application Code-Behind

```
Imports System.Windows.Threading

Class MainWindow

Private Sub progress_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs(Of Double)) Handles ProgressSlider.ValueChanged

    Dim valore As Integer = ProgressSlider.Value

    ProgressBarSF.GetMaxValue() = 100
    ProgressBarSF.ChangeValue(valore)

    Dim perc As Integer = valore

    LblProgress.Content = perc & "%"
    Dim prgrss As Double = valore / 100

    Dim redbrsh As SolidColorBrush = PrgBar.Resources("BrushRed")
    Dim grnbrsh As SolidColorBrush = PrgBar.Resources("BrushGreen")
    Dim ylwbrsh As SolidColorBrush = PrgBar.Resources("BrushYellow")

    If prgrss = 1D Then

        PrgBar.Foreground = grnbrsh

    ElseIf prgrss >= 0.95D And prgrss < 1D Then

        PrgBar.Foreground = ylwbrsh
    Else
        PrgBar.Foreground = redbrsh
    End If

    writereports()

End Sub

Public Sub writereports()
    With ProgressBarSF
        LblProva.Content = "Colore1: " & .GetColor1() & vbCrLf & _
                            "Colore2: " & .GetColor2() & vbCrLf & _
                            "Colore3: " & .GetColor3() & vbCrLf & _
                            "Valore Massimo: " & .GetMaxValue() & vbCrLf & _
                            "Valore Corrente: " & .GetCurrentProgress() & vbCrLf & _
                            "Colore Corrente: " & .GetCurrentColor() & vbCrLf
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    writereports()
End Sub

End Class
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by removing the custom control and using the default one